# Why does this query result in deadlock?

Tags: mysql, transaction, deadlock

I provide below the raw MySQL query and also the code in which I do that programatically. If two requests are being done at the same time results in the following error pattern:

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: `update user_chats set updated_at = 2018-06-29 10:07:13 where id = 1`)

If I execute the same query but without transaction block around it will work without error with many concurrent calls. Why ? (The transaction aquires lock, right ?)

Is there any way to solve this without locking the entire table ? (Want to try avoid table level locks)

I know that a lock is acquired for inserting/updating/deleting tables in MySql with InnoDB but still do not understand why the deadlock happens here and how to solve it in the most efficient way.

```
    START TRANSACTION;

    insert into `user_chat_messages` (`user_chat_id`, `from_user_id`, `content`)
        values (1, 2, 'dfasfdfk);
    update `user_chats`
        set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1;

    COMMIT;
```

Above is the raw query, but I do it in PHP Laravel Query Builder as follows:

```
    /**
     * @param UserChatMessageEntity $message
     * @return int
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function insertChatMessage(UserChatMessageEntity $message) : int
    {
        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            $id = $this->db->table('user_chat_messages')->insertGetId([
                    'user_chat_id' => $message->getUserChatId(),
                    'from_user_id' => $message->getFromUserId(),
                    'content' => $message->getContent()
                ]
            );

            //TODO results in lock error if many messages are sent same time
            $this->db->table('user_chats')
                ->where('id', $message->getUserChatId())
                ->update(['updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);

            $this->db->commit();
            return $id;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $this->db->rollBack();
            throw  $e;
        }
    }
```

DDL for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_chat_messages
(
    id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_chat_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    from_user_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_chat_messages_user_chat_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (user_chat_id) REFERENCES user_chats (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_chat_messages_from_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (from_user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
CREATE INDEX user_chat_messages_from_user_id_index ON user_chat_messages (from_user_id);
CREATE INDEX user_chat_messages_user_chat_id_index ON user_chat_messages (user_chat_id);


CREATE TABLE user_chats
(
    id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: How is `chat_user_messages.Id` calculated?  Can you post DDL for tables?

Comment: It is auto increment field. `id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` I did a test and if I remove the transaction the deadlock doesn't happen anymore. But anyway I need it to be done in transactional way, message get inserted only if also user_chats gets update. I updated question with the ddls for both tables involved

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The FOREIGN KEY `user_chat_messages_user_chat_id_foreign` is the cause of your deadlock, in this situation.

Fortunately, this is easy to reproduce given the information you've provided.

## Setup

```
CREATE DATABASE dba210949;
USE dba210949;

CREATE TABLE user_chats
(
    id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_chat_messages
(
    id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_chat_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    from_user_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_chat_messages_user_chat_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (user_chat_id) REFERENCES user_chats (id)
);

insert into user_chats (id,updated_at) values (1,NOW());
```

Note that I removed the `user_chat_messages_from_user_id_foreign` foreign key as it references the `users` table, which we don't have in our example. It is not important for reproducing the problem.

## Reproducing the deadlock

### Connection 1

```
USE dba210949;
START TRANSACTION;
insert into `user_chat_messages` (`user_chat_id`, `from_user_id`, `content`) values (1, 2, 'dfasfdfk');
```

### Connection 2

```
USE dba210949;
START TRANSACTION;
insert into `user_chat_messages` (`user_chat_id`, `from_user_id`, `content`) values (1, 2, 'dfasfdfk');
```

### Connection 1

```
update `user_chats` set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1;
```

At this point, Connection 1 is waiting.

### Connection 2

```
update `user_chats` set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1;
```

Here, Connection 2 throws a deadlock

> ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try
>   restarting transaction

## Retrying without the foreign key

Let's repeat the same steps, but with the following table structures. The only difference this time around is the removal of the `user_chat_messages_user_chat_id_foreign` foreign key.

```
CREATE DATABASE dba210949;
USE dba210949;

CREATE TABLE user_chats
(
    id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_chat_messages
(
    id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_chat_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    from_user_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

insert into user_chats (id,updated_at) values (1,NOW());
```

## Reproducing the same steps as before

### Connection 1

```
USE dba210949;
START TRANSACTION;
insert into `user_chat_messages` (`user_chat_id`, `from_user_id`, `content`) values (1, 2, 'dfasfdfk');
```

### Connection 2

```
USE dba210949;
START TRANSACTION;
insert into `user_chat_messages` (`user_chat_id`, `from_user_id`, `content`) values (1, 2, 'dfasfdfk');
```

### Connection 1

```
update `user_chats` set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1;
```

At this point, Connection 1 executes, instead of waiting like before.

### Connection 2

```
update `user_chats` set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1;
```

Connection 2 now is the one waiting now, but it has not deadlocked.

### Connection 1

```
commit;
```

Connection 2 now stops waiting and executes its command.

### Connection 2

```
commit;
```

Done, with no deadlock.

## Why?

Let's look at the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-07-04 10:38:31 0x7fad84161700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 42061, ACTIVE 55 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 140383222380288, query id 81 localhost root updating
update `user_chats` set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3711 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `dba210949`.`user_chats` trx id 42061 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000a44b; asc      K;;
 2: len 7; hex b90000012d0110; asc     -  ;;
 3: len 4; hex 5b3ca335; asc [< 5;;
 4: len 4; hex 5b3ca335; asc [< 5;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 42062, ACTIVE 46 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 3, OS thread handle 140383222109952, query id 82 localhost root updating
update `user_chats` set `updated_at` = '2018-06-28 08:33:14' where `id` = 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3711 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `dba210949`.`user_chats` trx id 42062 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000a44b; asc      K;;
 2: len 7; hex b90000012d0110; asc     -  ;;
 3: len 4; hex 5b3ca335; asc [< 5;;
 4: len 4; hex 5b3ca335; asc [< 5;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3711 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `dba210949`.`user_chats` trx id 42062 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000a44b; asc      K;;
 2: len 7; hex b90000012d0110; asc     -  ;;
 3: len 4; hex 5b3ca335; asc [< 5;;
 4: len 4; hex 5b3ca335; asc [< 5;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

You can see that transaction 1 has a **lock_mode X** on the PRIMARY key of `user_chats`, while transaction 2 has **lock_mode S**, and is waiting for **lock_mode X**. That is a result of it obtaining a shared lock first (from our `INSERT` statement), and then an exclusive lock (from our `UPDATE`).

So, what is happening is Connection 1 grabs the shared lock first, and then Connection 2 grabs a shared lock on the same record. That's fine, for now, as they are both shared locks.

Connection 1 then tries to upgrade to an exclusive lock to perform the UPDATE, only to find that connection 2 has a lock already. Shared and exclusive locks don't mix well, as you can probably deduce by their name. That is why it waits after the `UPDATE` command on Connection 1.

Then Connection 2 tries to `UPDATE`, which requires an exclusive lock, and InnoDB goes "whelp, I'm never going to be able to fix this situation on my own", and declares a deadlock. It kills off Connection 2, releases the shared lock that Connection 2 was holding, and allows Connection 1 to complete normally.

## Solution(s)

At this point, you are probably ready to stop with the yap yap yap and want a solution. Here are the my suggestions, in order of my personal preference.

### 1. Avoid the update altogether

Don't bother with the `updated_at` column in the `user_chats` table at all. Instead, add a composite index on `user_chat_messages` for the columns (`user_chat_id`,`created_at`).

```
ALTER TABLE user_chat_messages
ADD INDEX `latest_message_for_user_chat` (`user_chat_id`,`created_at`)
```

Then, you can obtain the most recent updated time with the following query.

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM user_chat_messages WHERE user_chat_id = 1
```

This query will execute extremely quickly due to the index, and doesn't require you to store the latest `updated_at` time in the `user_chats` table as well. This helps avoid data duplication, which is why it is my preferred solution.

Make sure to dynamically set the `id` to the `$message->getUserChatId()` value, and not hard coded to `1`, as in my example.

This is essentially what Rick James is suggesting.

### 2. Lock the tables to serialize requests

```
SELECT id FROM user_chats WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE
```

Add this `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to the start of your transaction, and it will serialize your requests. As before, make sure to dynamically set the `id` to the `$message->getUserChatId()` value, and not hard coded to `1`, as in my example.

This is what Gerard H. Pille is suggesting.

### 3. Drop the foreign key

Sometimes, it is just easier to remove the source of the deadlock. Just drop the `user_chat_messages_user_chat_id_foreign` foreign key, and problem solved.

I don't particularly like this solution in general, as I love data integrity (which the foreign key provides), but sometimes you need to make trade offs.

### 4. Retry the command after deadlock

This is the recommended solution for deadlocks in general. Just catch the error, and retry the entire request. However, it is easiest to implement if you prepared for it from the start, and updating legacy code may be difficult. Given the fact that there are easier solutions (like 1 and 2 above) is why this is my least recommended solution for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer ! (I cannot upvote unfortunately due to missing reputation). The id is hardcoded only here in the question, but in my real code is of course dynamic. The userchatid is known beforehand and set to the UserChatMessage object. I will try also myself all the steps that you provided so I totally understand and avoid in future such a case. Thanks ! I had solved this issue before 2 days as Gerard H. Pille suggested and is working great. WIll also try also all of your solutions for learning purposes

Comment: Yes, great answer.  (I did upvote it.)  Yet another reason why FKs can be more bother than worth.

Comment: @KristiJorgji Sounds good. I gave your question an upvote (it deserved it anyway, with all the good information to reproduce the problem) so that may give you enough rep to upvote and choose an answer. Since Gerard's solution fixed your issue, I would suggest accepting his answer, but you can upvote everyone's answer that was useful, as well.

Comment: Excellent answer. I had similar issue. Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As the first step in your transaction, take a lock on $this->db->table('user_chats')->where('id', $message->getUserChatId()).  This will avoid a deadlock.

Comment: So you are suggesting to first do a select statement even though I do not need the result then proceed the rest as is actually ? Please provide me the details of this solution some explanation so I understand how this solves the problem and I learn form it

Comment: Do you understand a deadlock?   I suggested to take a lock (on Oracle this would be a "select ... for update"), so as to be sure you'll be able to update, no one will come in between (your supposedly very short transaction).

Comment: That is the same syntax in MySql also. Great thanks will do that then take a lock for that row

Answer (score 0):

If there only one row in `user_chats`?  If not, what is the semantics of `id`?  Is it a "user"?  Or a "chat number"?  Or something else?

It sounds like all connections are trying to bump the id of the last chat (id=1).  If you need that, consider tossing the `UPDATE` and doing this instead when you want the latest date:

```
SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM user_chat_messages.
```

Comment: The id is 1 is only for the example that I provided here, in real code may be different ids depending on the chat. That deadlock happens when a user sends multiple messages to the same chat (ex chat with id 1). Of course I can block js frontend button until a call is finished etc but for learning purpose of building something robust I wanted to be able avoid the deadlock even when many requests were made to insert message to the same chat (particular chat id) in the same time. I resolved the issue by first selecting for update the user_chat as the first thing that happens in the transaction